# Find Index In An Array Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array of quantities and I would like to find where in this array a number is found. So if a user entered 16 the function would return between index 6 & 7 because 16 is greater than 15 but less than 20.

In the wider picture this index would be used in a lookup to find a price band for the desired quantity.

**Edit**

***HTML Markup***

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="row">Quantity</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-0" scope="col">0</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-1" scope="col">1</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-2" scope="col">2</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-3" scope="col">3</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-4" scope="col">4</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-5" scope="col">5</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-6" scope="col">10</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-7" scope="col">15</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-8" scope="col">20</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-9" scope="col">30</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-10" scope="col">40</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-11" scope="col">50</th>
        <th id="js-QuantityID-12" scope="col">60</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Price (inc. VAT)</th>
        <td id="js-PriceID-0">0.00</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-1">45.60</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-2">38.40</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-3">32.40</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-4">34.56</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-5">30.72</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-6">26.80</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-7">21.60</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-8">20.60</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-9">17.60</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-10">16.60</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-11">15.60</td>
        <td id="js-PriceID-12">14.00</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***Working Script***

```
function getTableContents() {
    var productArray = [];

    jQuery("th[id^='js-QuantityID-']").each(function () {
        var n = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace('js-QuantityID-', ''); // get the number from the id

        productArray.push({
            qty: parseInt(jQuery(this).text()),
            price: parseFloat(jQuery('#js-PriceID-' + n).text().replace('£',''))
        });
    });

    return productArray = cleanArray(productArray);
}
```

**Answer**

The problem was due to getting the Quantity as a string, upon parsing as an Integer this fixed my issue @Michael Geary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to set up parallel arrays with matching elements like the `price` and `quantity` arrays in your example. This is error-prone and hard to visually match up which price goes with which quantity.

Instead, you should use a single array where each array element is an object that combines the quantity level and price:

```
var priceBands = [
    { qty:  1, price: '£45.60' },
    { qty:  2, price: '£38.40' },
    { qty:  3, price: '£32.40' },
    { qty:  4, price: '£32.10' },
    { qty:  5, price: '£34.56' },
    { qty: 10, price: '£30.72' },
    { qty: 15, price: '£26.80' },
    { qty: 20, price: '£21.60' },
    { qty: 30, price: '£21.00' },
    { qty: 40, price: '£21.00' }
];
```

Now it's easy to see which price goes with which quantity, and there's no question of having the same number of elements in both arrays.

(BTW I'm curious why the price goes *up* at 5 items!)

If that notation seems too tedious, you can easily streamline it:

```
var priceBands = makePriceBands([
    ' 1: £45.60',
    ' 2: £38.40',
    ' 3: £32.40',
    ' 4: £32.10',
    ' 5: £34.56',
    '10: £30.72',
    '15: £26.80',
    '20: £21.60',
    '30: £21.00',
    '40: £21.00',
]);
```

That produces the same array of objects listed previously, using this function to convert the more concise notation:

```
function makePriceBands( bandsIn ) {
    var bands = [];
    for( var i = 0;  i < bandsIn.length;  ++i ) {
        var band = bandsIn[i].split(/: */));
        bands.push({ qty: +band[0], price: band[1] });
    }
    return bands;
}
```

For modern browsers you could write this a little more simply:

```
function makePriceBands( bands ) {
    return bands.map( function( b ) {
        var band = b.split(/: */));
        return { qty: +band[0], price: band[1] };
    });
}
```

But the first version will work on any old browser.

Either way, the code to find the proper price is simple. Walk backwards through the array until you reach the element where your your input quantity is greater than or equal to the quantity in the array element.

We'll make this a function that expects a `prices` array as a parameter, so you can use it for different products by passing in different arrays.

Also, you didn't specify in your question what to do when the input quantity is *equal* to one of the price level quantities, so I made the assumption that, for example, if you have 10 or more, you get the price level for quantity 10. (In other words, you don't have to buy 11 to get the quantity 10 price.)

```
function priceForQuantity( prices, n ) {
    for( var i = prices.length - 1;  i >= 0;  --i ) {
        if( n >= prices[i].qty ) {
            return prices[i].price;
        }
    }
    return '£0.00';
}
```

Or you could walk forward through the array, but I find it easier to think about this particular problem by walking backwards.

You can test this code with a few example quantities, making sure to test the border conditions of one greater and one less than a particular quantity level:

```
function test( n ) {
    console.log( n, priceForQuantity( priceBands, n ) );
}

test( 0 );
test( 1 );
test( 3 );
test( 5 );
test( 6 );
test( 9 );
test( 10 );
test( 39 );
test( 40 );
test( 41 );
```

This will log:

```
0 "£0.00"
1 "£45.60"
3 "£32.40"
5 "£34.56"
6 "£34.56"
9 "£34.56"
10 "£30.72"
39 "£21.00"
40 "£21.00"
41 "£21.00"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, whilst in your case this works 100% percent. However if you see my current script above, the indexes seem to become skewed, for you curiosity its just a typo (Test Data).

Comment: Fantastic answer as before, lessons have been made along the way. See my answer to the issue I faced beforehand with the data skew.

Comment: +1, I was going down the same path however got side-tracked and forgot to post it yesterday. Here it is anyway, for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/wjte9b2x/2/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for including the additional details about your use case vis-a-vis pricing bands. I think something along these lines should work well for what you want to do; notice the change in the quantity array -- I changed "40+" to 41, but as long as you have the same array length for `qtys` and `prices`, you only need to enter the highest quantity/lowest price once ... any quantity above that threshold will get the correct price when it finds the end of the quantity array. http://jsfiddle.net/4oyrd0d2/

```
var qtyOrdered = 45; // From order/bid input

var qtys =   [1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,30,40,41]; // Quantity Array
var prices = ["£45.60", "£38.40", "£32.40", "£32.10", "£34.56", "£30.72", "£26.8", "£21.6", "£21.0", "£21.0", "£20.0"]; // Price Bands

var qtyIdx = 0, qtyBand, priceIdx;
do {
    priceIdx = qtyIdx; // assigns the current price, only changed -after- each 'while' condition passes
    qtyBand = qtys[++qtyIdx];
}
while(qtyBand <= qtyOrdered && priceIdx < qtys.length);

var effectivePrice = prices[priceIdx];
```

Comment: From Looking at the JS Fiddle this looks like the best answer in my case. I shall implement this tomorrow morning and let you know on the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is sorted, you can use a [dichotomic search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search):

```js
function dicSearch(arr, item, from=0, to=arr.length) {
  if(from === to) return [to-1, to];
  var mid = Math.floor((from + to) / 2);
  if(arr[mid] > item) return dicSearch(arr, item, from, mid);
  if(arr[mid] < item) return dicSearch(arr, item, mid+1, to);
  return [mid, mid];
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40];
dicSearch(arr, 0);  // [-1,0]
dicSearch(arr, 15); // [6,6]
dicSearch(arr, 16); // [6,7]
dicSearch(arr, 50); // [9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 16,
    index = ary.indexOf(ary.filter(function (item, index) {
        var first = item,
            second = ary[index + 1] || false;
        return value >= first && (!second || value <= second);
    })),
    range = 'between index ' + index + ' and ' + (index + 1);
```

Comment: makes sure to kill the + on the 40+

Comment: Just Add parseInt or parseFloat in all of them. When working with money, you'll probably want to not work with floating points and just * 100 and / 100 after. There's probably also a magical version with array.reduce that'll be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier to grasp than a filter

```js
var q = [1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,30,40],
price = [45.60,38.40,32.40,32.10,34.56,30.72,26.8,21.6,21.0,21.0];
function getPrice(num) {
  for (var i = q.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    if (num >= q[i]) {
      return q[i]+" @ £"+price[i].toFixed(2)+": £"+(num*price[i]).toFixed(2);
    }
  } 
  return "Not understandable quantity";
}
alert(getPrice(26));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this search,this should work too.
In this,if inputted number is same as any array element.If goes to the lower value,you could choose to go the higher value if you wish to.

```
var t=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10", "15", "20", "30", "40"];

var y=prompt("Enter a value:");
var i=0;
$.each(t,function(u,v){
    console.log(u);
   if(parseFloat(y)<parseFloat(v) && parseFloat(y)>parseFloat(t[u-1]))
   {
       i=u-1;
   } 
   if(parseFloat(y)==parseFloat(v))
   {
       i=u-1;
   }
});
alert("Element between index "+(i)+ " and "+ (i+1));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktozktch/25/